# Convert URL query parameters to object - preserve type?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I have the following URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5Dsh9xXuo8&paused=true&volume=100
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
var parsedUrl = {
  v: "-5Dsh9xXuo8",
  paused: true,
  volume: 100
};
```

So, I'm using a very simple solution:

```
_urlToVideoOptions: function(url) {
  var queryParameters = url.search.substr(1);

  var videoOptions = {};
  queryParameters.split('&').forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split('=');
    videoOptions[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });

  return videoOptions;
}
```

This results in:

```
var parsedUrl = {
  v: "-5Dsh9xXuo8",
  paused: "true",
  volume: "100"
};
```

where paused and volume are strings rather than boolean/number.

Is there a generic way of converting these values to their appropriate types? Or do I need to call parseInt, use a custom 'parseBool' method, etc... and, given failures, fall back to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way.

```
_urlToVideoOptions: function(url) {
  var queryParameters = url.search.substr(1);

  var videoOptions = {};
  queryParameters.split('&').forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split('=');
    var val = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
    if (val == "true" || val == "false")
        val = !!val;
    else if (!isNaN(val)) {
        if (val.indexOf('.') != -1)
            val = parseFloat(val);
        else
            val = parseInt(val);
    }
    videoOptions[item[0]] = val;
  });

  return videoOptions;
}
```